# Google JAX 1D convolutional neural network

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, jax

I'm trying to implement a 1D convolutional neural network in **Google Jax** with *stax.GeneralConv()* (https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/jax/experimental/stax.html#GeneralConv).
I have a 1 dimensional input array with 18 and output array with 6 entries. I want to implement a CNN with kernel width 3 as follows:

```
init_random_params, conv_net = stax.serial(
    GeneralConv(('NC','IO','NC'),1,(3,),padding='SAME'), # dimension_numbers = ('NC','IO','NC')
    LogSoftmax,
    Dense(6),
)
```

with the initial network parameters:

```
rng = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
_, init_params = init_random_params(rng, (18,))
```

But I get the following error:

```
stax.py", line 75, in <listcomp>
    next(filter_shape_iter) for c in rhs_spec]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

stax requires the dimension number *rhs_spec* to be at least 2 characters long, but I use a 1 dimensional filter. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but I expect that a 1d convolution still requires one direction over which to convolve, e.g.

```py
Conv2d = functools.partial(GeneralConv, ('NHWC', 'HWIO', 'NHWC'))
Conv1d = functools.partial(GeneralConv, ('NHC', 'HIO', 'NHC'))
```

In other words, dropping the `W` axis to go from 2d to 1d convolutions.

The input shape corresponding to `NHC` is `(batch_size, sequence_length, num_channels)`.

Note that even though the number of channels might be 1, you still need include that axis because `GeneralConv` does an index lookup along the lines of `num_channels = input_shape['NHC'.index('C')]`.